# How to calculate current internet connection speed with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, monitoring, python-module

I need to find out the current internet speed of my os to use in my program, there are several modules to calculate maximum internet connection speed by garbage downloads like speedtest-cli and pyspeed but I can not find any way or module to calculate the current internet connection speed

Comment: Download a big file, figure out how long it takes? Divide size by duration and you got speed.

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as a general "internet speed". *Any* path between your device and a target device can have different performance. Using the approach of the modules you already found and hoping the bottleneck is your connection to the world (assuming you have only one!) is the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
import speedtest

s = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

From here you can use:

```
print('Download speed is:', s.download())
```

The output is in bits per second, so obviously divide by 1 000 000 to convert to Mbps

Comment: The question already mentions speedtest. How does this answer provide any new information?